# How to map custom IP to the output pin on FPGA

Tags: vhdl, xilinx, vivado, zynq

I have a custom IP created with 2 output pin (en1_out and dir1_out) [image]

May I know how to map these two pin to the PMod pin on FPGA (pin Y11 and pin AA11)? I have tried to open the elaborate design and in the I/O Ports I can't find these two pin.

[image]

I am using ZedBoard and Vivado 2016.1
Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are they broken all the way out to your top-level design? If not, you have to define some external ports in your block diagram, and then assign them in your constraints (XDC) file. Otherwise, those pins will remain internal / not-connected.

Right-click in the BD, and create a port (Ctrl+K):

[image]

Then, when you auto-generate the wrapper for the block diagram, the new port should be present for you to connect to.